# Bayesian optimisation basics (illustrative example)

Tags: optimization, notation, bayesian

I'm trying to follow a basic example of Bayesian optimisation described in the paper by
Močkus, J. "On Bayesian methods for seeking the extremum." (Optimization Techniques IFIP Technical Conference. Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 1975, page 401). A better formatted text is available [here](https://books.google.de/books?id=VuKoCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA6&lpg=PA6&dq=bayesian%20optimization%20recurrent%20equation&source=bl&ots=_EIu0ZVw1Y&sig=fp0VOLd-rY2D2MAS6tkWqGRUQwM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYqsymptzOAhWEChoKHQaeBpUQ6AEIMTAC#v=onepage&q=bayesian%20optimization%20recurrent%20equation&f=false) (see page 8).

---

We want to minimise the following function in example 2.2.1 in the book: $f(x) = (x - \omega)^2$, where $x \in A, A = [-1, 1]$; $\omega \in \Omega, \Omega=[-1, 1]$. In general, $A$ is a compact set and $\Omega$ is a set of indices $\omega$ corresponding to all continuous functions of $x \in A$. $N=1$, that is, we have a single observation. The *a priori* density function is $p(\omega) = 1/2$, $\omega \in \Omega$.

To proceed with the recurrent equations (2.2.1 in the book):

\begin{align}
u_1(z_1) = \inf_{x\in A}E\{f(x)\mid z_1\}\\
u_0 = \inf_{x \in A}\{u(x, f(x))\}
\end{align}
And here is the next step which I have troubles with:
\begin{align}
E\{f(x) \mid z_1\} = \begin{cases}
    (x - \omega_1)^2, & \omega_1 \in \Omega, \omega_2 \in^- \Omega\\
    (x - \omega_2)^2, & \omega_1 \in^- \Omega, \omega_2 \in \Omega\\
    1/2(x-\omega_1)^2 + 1/2(x-\omega_2)^2, & \omega_1 \in \Omega, \omega_2 \in \Omega.
  \end{cases}
\end{align}
, where $z_1 = (f(x_1), x_1)$ is our observation.

---

1) I have difficulties understanding why we have three cases. Perhaps, the hint lies within the notation $\in^-$ I've never encountered before. Does it mean "negative element of"?

2) To me, the notation $[a, b]$ is an interval from $a$ to $b$. How come $p(\omega)=1/2$ for $\omega \in [-1, 1]$? Surely, it should be a set $\{-1, 1\}$, shouldn't it? Yet, it's still in $[a, b]$ in both manuscripts.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Starting afresh sometimes helps. I'll write down my interpretation of the example and would be really grateful to anyone who could glance through it if it makes sense.

---

We first note that

1. $\in^-$ means $\not\in$;
2. $[a, b]$ is the usual interval $\{x: a\leq x \leq b \}$. Since, $\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{2}dx = 1$, $p(\omega):=\frac{1}{2}$ is a valid density function.

So, for our first observation $z_1 = (f(x_1), x_1)$, we have two possibilities for $\omega$, namely $\omega_{1,2} = x_1 \pm \sqrt{f(x_1)}$. We have three cases for the $E\{f(x_1) \mid z_1 \}$: a) $\omega_1 \in \Omega$; b) $\omega_2 \in \Omega$; or c) both.

Following the rest of the example from the book is quite straightforward. We arrive at $E\{u_1(x, f(x))\} = \int_{\Omega_x} (x-\omega)^2 d\omega$, where $\Omega_x = [max(2x-1, -1), min(2x+1, 1)]$, that looks like:
[image]

Hence, to minimise it we take $x_1 := \pm 1$ as out first observation. In the second round we choose:
\begin{equation}
x_2 := \begin{cases}
1 - \sqrt{f(1)}, & x_1 = 1 \\
-1+\sqrt{f(-1)}, & x_1 = -1
\end{cases}
\end{equation}